# How to use placeholders with LIMIT in MySQL (Node.JS)?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to execute query with placeholders using node.js and mysql. But the `LIMIT` placeholder doesn't seem to work, because the value after it should be without quotes. Here is my query:

```
SELECT userName, clicks FROM users ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT ?
```

How can I obtain the behaviour I need using placeholders, and is it even possible? Here is the whole code statement, where `data.topUsersCount` is an Integer value:

```
con.query("SELECT userName, clicks FROM users ORDER BY clicks DESC LIMIT ?", [data.topUsersCount], (err, topUsersData) => {
    // Handle data
});
```

I also tried to use double placeholder `??`, but it also did not work.